# Plotly dash local css only loaded by hot reload

Tags: python, plotly-dash

My local css file is not loaded at the start of the application.
But if I modify the css file and have hot reload active it loads.

In the example below I have css in the file assets/my.css which colors the dropdown dark after I start the server and then add a whitespace to the css file.

How can I make sure the app immediately uses the local stylesheet from the start?

CSS:

```
.dash-bootstrap .Select-control {
    height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px);
    font-size: 0.9375rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #222;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  }
```

--

```
# stylesheet in assets only works after hot reload.

import plotly.express as px
from dash import html, dcc, Dash
# Load Data
df = px.data.tips()
# Build App
app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("JupyterDash Demo"),
    dcc.Graph(id='graph', figure=px.scatter(
        df, x="total_bill", y="tip", color="tip",
        render_mode="webgl", title="Tips"
    )),
    html.Label([
        "colorscale",
        dcc.Dropdown(
            className="dash-bootstrap",
            id='colorscale-dropdown', clearable=False,
            value='plasma', options=[
                {'label': c, 'value': c}
                for c in px.colors.named_colorscales()
            ])
    ]),
    ])

# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
app.run_server(dev_tools_hot_reload=True, port=8068)
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I tested suddenly started working after I posted my question.

You can add
`html.Link(rel='stylesheet', href='/assets/my.css')`
as an additional parameter in the Div element.

Replace my.css with the name of your stylesheet.

I still want to know why I need this in the first place.
The local css file should work out of the box without needing hot reload or adding the "link".